# Qt program deploy

Tags: c++, qt, deployment

I just wrote a Qt program, and build it under Release type, it work fine in QtCreator, but if I double click the exe in windows, it says it can't locate something in QtCore4.dll, so which QtCore4.dll should I actually add to it's folder? I'm using Qt4.7.3

Btw is it because I installed TortoiseHg? and it messed up with the envoiurnment vars. But I did copy QtCore4.dll from my QtSDK folder. And it still doesn't work.

Comment: Copy other Qt dlls as well. Tortoise definitely uses Qt and might be causing this problem.

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-windows.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the used Qt and mingw dlls in the same folder wher your program is. The you need to package these with the program.