# Export executable program from QtCreator

Tags: c++

I want to export an executable program from Qtcreator, the program works fine inside the Qtcreator but outside I got an error message, "missing QT5CORED.DLL" so I add it to the binary file but it keeps asking for other dependencies.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Qt program deploy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11449412/qt-program-deploy)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put that dll in the executable folder. The dll would be in the Qt folder i assume, check it.

Also please note that is a debug dll (the last D in the name), you‘d want to ship a release build instead of a debug one.

Answer (score 0):

You can find necessary QT dll's in:  QT Directory \mingw48_32\bin
and windows runtime dll's in:  QT Directory \mingw48_32\plugins\platforms
path is for mingw compiler

Comment: This is a list of dlls that i have to add, a folder platform with files qwindows.dll and qminimal.dll must be included.  

Qt5Core.dll

Qt5Gui.dll

Qt5SerialPort.dll

Qt5Widgets.dll

icudt51.dll

icuin51.dll

icuuc51.dll

libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll

libstdc++-6.dll

libwinpthread-1.dll

 
qminimal.dll

qwindows.dll